# Embedded Python: Py_Initialize: can't initialize sys standard streams

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio-2012, stream

The problem is a bit more specific. I am using the 3.3.3 version of Python and have built it myself. When I embed it into my program `_Py_InitializeEx_Private()` exits with this error `Py_Initialize: can't initialize sys standard streams`

Background: I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Express and am starting Python in a boost thread. 
Boiled down, the call looks like that:

```
int SubSysPython::Start()
{
    m_PythonThread = boost::thread(&SubSysPython::StartPython, this);
    return m_RC;
}

void SubSysPython::StartPython()
{
    Py_Initialize();
    FILE* fp = nullptr;
    fopen_s(&fp, startScript.c_str(), "r");
    PyRun_SimpleFile(fp, startScript.c_str());
    fclose(fp);
    Py_Finalize();
}
```

The libraries are copied from the working build, the python lib folder is original (copy from the 3.3.3 binary dist). I tried to trace down the problem in the debugger, but I failed to understand the python internals in a reasonable time.

Does someone have any ideas what could be the cause? I suppose it's just a minor problem I'm not aware of but I'm a bit short on options at the moment..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Python ticket to this problem. Somehow I failed to find it first time but it's definitely relevant. The streams are bugged in non-terminal applications. It may be fixed in the Python code with:

```
#ifdef MS_WINDOWS
    if (!is_valid_fd(fd) || GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE) == NULL) {
#else
    if (!is_valid_fd(fd)) {
#endif
```

at the !is_valid_fd() passages.

The ticket may be found here: [Issue17797](http://bugs.python.org/issue17797)